# Приложение падает, если попытаться его закрыть при открытом дочернем окне

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

Есть главное окно MainWindow, есть его дочернее окно, которое создается в слоте главного окна MainWindow - MapsManager(this). Вся проблема в том, что если дочернее окно открыто и я нажимаю на крестик главного окна(ну т.е. пытаюсь закрыть главное окно, а значит и весь аппликейшин), то  попадаю в деструктор MainWindow, а затем уже в деструктор MapsManager, затем в лямбду, там вышибает сегфолт на любой строке с доступом к ui. Почему деструктор MainWindow срабатывает раньше дочернего?

```
void MainWindow::slotMapsManager()
{
    // Проверить не запущен ли виджет менеджера карт
    if(mapsManagerPtr_)
        return;

    if(foundPointPtr_)
        foundPointPtr_->close();

    WaterBody::getInstance().hidePoint();

    // Установить максимальный размер виджета для повышения точность и удобства калибровки,
    setWindowState(Qt::WindowMaximized);
    // Зафиксировать размер виджета
    setFixedSize(width(), height());

    // Необходимо сделать неактивными кнопки поиска и создания точек
    ui->pushButtonCreateGamePoint->setEnabled(false);
    ui->pushButtonFindGamePoint->setEnabled(false);

    ui->menuBar->setEnabled(false);

    ui->lineEditPointX->setValidator(new QIntValidator(0, 9999, this));
    ui->lineEditPointY->setValidator(new QIntValidator(0, 9999, this));

    ui->lineEditPointX->setReadOnly(true);
    ui->lineEditPointY->setReadOnly(true);

    ui->lineEditPointX->clear();
    ui->lineEditPointY->clear();

    mapsManagerPtr_ = new MapsManager(this);

    // Соединяет сигнал закрытия виджета с лямбдой
    connect(mapsManagerPtr_, &MapsManager::destroyed, this, [this]()
    {
        // Вернуть стандартные минимальные и максимальные размеры виджета для отмены фиксации
        setMaximumSize(QWIDGETSIZE_MAX, QWIDGETSIZE_MAX);
        setMinimumSize(MINIMUM_WIDTH, MINIMUM_HEIGHT);

        //WaterBody::getInstance().showPoint();

        // Возвращаем активность кнопкам поиска и создания точек
        ui->pushButtonCreateGamePoint->setEnabled(true);
        ui->pushButtonFindGamePoint->setEnabled(true);

        ui->menuBar->setEnabled(true);

        // Валидатор для полей отображения координат. Необязательный минус, затем 0-999
        ui->lineEditPointX->setValidator(new QRegExpValidator(QRegExp("(-\\d{2})|(\\d{3})"), this));
        ui->lineEditPointY->setValidator(new QRegExpValidator(QRegExp("(-\\d{2})|(\\d{3})"), this));

        ui->lineEditPointX->setReadOnly(false);
        ui->lineEditPointY->setReadOnly(false);

        ui->lineEditPointX->clear();
        ui->lineEditPointY->clear();
    });

    mapsManagerPtr_->show();
}
```

Comment: вроде и не видать ничего криминального... а если в лямбде убрать все обращения, вызывающие сегфолт, то дальше он заходит в деструктор главного окна?

Comment: Опс! Я таки попадаю, в деструктор главного окна раньше, чем в деструктор дочернего, что с закомментаренной лямбдой, что без. Это разве нормальное поведение? Сейчас перепишу описание проблемы. Вчера вроде бы не попадал в дестр главного, хотя я правил некоторые вещи с тех пор. Теперь понятно почему ui в этот момент уже нет, но непонятно почему сперва не пытается удалиться все дочернее, а уже потом главное.

Comment: Кажется решил проблему дописав ui = nullptr; в деструкторе MainWindow сразу после delete ui; И установив проверку в лямбде if(!ui) return; Выглядит костыльно конечно. Может есть более нормальный подход? Или эта необходимость таки обусловлена лямбдой с сигналом destroyed и так необходимо было делать изначально? А очередность деструкторов совершенно нормальная, получается?

Comment: ну смотрите, ui принадлежит QMainWindow, а deleteChildren вызывается в самом конце деструктора QObject. Так как порядок вызова деструкторов от дочернего к родительскому, то к моменту выброса сигнала destoroyed от вашего ui уже ничего не осталось, т.к он удалился еще в деструкторе QMainWindow.

Comment: Звучит конечно противоречиво, получается, что первоначально все же вызывается родительский деструктор, после удаления практически всего и вся в нем вызывается дочерний, а после него опять родительский, где терминальные операции продолжаются. Выходит, порядок терминальных вызовов не от дочернего к родительскому, а какой-то круговорот. Благодарю Вас за помощь в решении проблемы!

Comment: Вы путаете поведение при вызове деструктора объекта с поведением класса QObject при удалении дочерних объектов. Единственное, что вам во втором случае гарантируется - это то, что дочерние объекты будут удалены. Что касается более красивого решения вашей проблемы, то возможно стоит переопределить closeevent вашего MapManager и в нем бросать какой-нибудь спец.сигнал, который будет прикрепляться к вашей лямбде.

Comment: http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/objecttrees.html вот тут, кстати, подтверждается то, что я написал

Comment: Оформил ответ. Отметьте его как правильный, если он вам помог.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ваш `QMainWindow` осуществляет удаление дочерних объектов только в конструкторе своего самого базового класса `QObject`, который, как известно, вызывается в самом конце. К тому моменту уже не существует никаких членов-данных, в частности `ui`, класса `QMainWindow`, т.к его деструктор вызывался раньше. Что касается более красивого решения вашей проблемы, то возможно стоит переопределить `closeevent` вашего `MapManager` и в нем бросать какой-нибудь спец.сигнал, который будет прикрепляться к вашей лямбде.